# Unique solution to sin(2a) and cos(2a)

Tags: trigonometry

I'm a bit confused as to how to solve for $2\alpha^*$ using the equation 6.36 in the excerpt below. I know how to solve for it individually (ie acos and asin) but how do I solve them together to get the **unique** solution?

Any help will be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: think of $$\sin(2x)^2+\cos(2x)^2=1$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Would you always write $\sin (\alpha)^{2}$ rather than $\sin^{2}\alpha$ for that identitiy (or any others)?

Comment: oik i will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually only the sign of the sine and cosine suffice to discuss the quadrant. I advise you to compute the angle from the first formula and check the signs with the second.

Programming languages support an [$\text{atan2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function for this very purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I thought atan2 was the easiest thing to use but I couldn't justify to myself how I was arriving at the decision.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, that formula brings up memories.
Over thirty years ago,
I derived the formula
for the line
that minimizes
the sum of the squares of the distances
from a set of points in a plane
to the line,
the distances being measured
by the perpendicular to the line.

It turns out that
the line always passes through
the mean of the data points,
and,
of all lines that pass
through this mean,
one has the minimum sum of squares of distance
and
one has the maximum sum of squares of distance
and these two are orthogonal.
Initially I had to compute the two
and see which was the smaller,
but I later found a way
of directly getting the minimum.

The equation I got for the angle
is the one in your document.
I'll see if I can excavate my document.

(I know that this is really a comment, but long comments are a pain.)